# pd.read_sql(sql) If sql has two columns of the same field, the result is only one column of fields

Tags: python, pandas, read-sql

pd.read_sql(sql)  If sql has two columns of the same field, the result is only one column of fields

pd.read_sql() dont work ?

```
import pandas as pd

sql = "select name, name, age from table;"
df = pd.read_sql(sql, con)

print(df.columns) 
# name, age
```

it work

```
with conn.cursor() as a:
    a.execute(sql)
    lines = a.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
```

Comment: yes, Pandas can have only unique names of the columns, try using an alias for one of the duplicates columns, such as `select name, name AS name2, age from table;`